# How to customise a key in json response?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

Relationship: Table has many Users.

I'm using "includes" to print the table details with the associated users as:

```
Table.includes(:users)
```

But if I use conditions for users, say, users.active as:

```
Table.includes(:users).where( :users => { active: true } )
```

I'm getting the tables with users that are active. That works good. But if a table doesn't have active user, it returns empty.
What I need was, to print the table details even if there is no active user (in that case, excluding the user part). i.e., if there is any active user, it has to be printed along the table else only table has to be printed. 
So I wrote a filter method in model as:

```
has_many :active_users, class_name: "User", :conditions => { active: 'yes'}
```

And, in controller: `Table.includes(:active_users)`.

Now, for json response:

```
render :json => { :table => @table.as_json(:include => :active_users) }
```

So the key comes as "active_users".

But I like to have that key as "users" and i'm stuck finding solutions. Can anyone suggest a sol please.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `Table#as_json` to include the users

```
def as_json(opts={})
  super.merge(
    users: active_users.as_json(only: [:id, :username, ...]
  )
end
```

I'd recommend whitelisting the user attributes to ensure you don't expose any sensitive information.